# How to move files and directories excluding one specific directory to this directory

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

[image]

inside the directory

```
~/domains/annejulie.blue-world.pl/git
```

i want to get all files and directories excluding **annejulie.blue-world.pl.git** directory and move them into that directory (**annejulie.blue-world.pl.git**)

How to do this in terminal with **find** and **grep** command? is it possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask questions about Linux commands.

Comment: `mv * annejulie.blue-world.pl.git`

Comment: no, because it will move directory `annejulie.blue-world.pl.git` to itself

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version do you use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Execute the following command first in terminal. This extends regexes.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Now you can execute the following mv command

```
mv !(<file/dir not to be moved>) <Path to dest>
```

For example, If you are at ~/Test and you need to move all except ~/Test/Dest to ~/Test/Dest, you can execute it as given below, assuming you are at ~/Test

```
mv !(Dest) ~/Test/Dest
```

Answer (score 2):

With `find`, assuming your `find` supports `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name annejulie.blue-world.pl.git -exec echo mv {} annejulie.blue-word.pl.git \;
```

This doesn't perform the move, rather it prints on the terminal what operations it will perform. Remove the `echo` after the `-exec` word if you're happy with the result.

If you have an `mv` that supports the `-t` option, you can use this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name annejulie.blue-world.pl.git -exec echo mv -t annejulie.blue-word.pl.git {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`, this POSIX-compatible should do:

```
find \( \! -name '.' -type d -prune -o \! -type d \) \! -name annejulie.blue-world.pl.git -exec echo mv {} annejulie.blue-word.pl.git \;
```

it works but it's really ugly.

---

Of course, the best option is to use

```
mv -- * annejulie.blue-world.pl.git
```

and let `mv` complain that it can't move to a subdirectory of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`:

```
cd ~/domains/annejulie.blue-world.pl/git
find . -and -not -path './annejulie.blue-world.pl.git*' -exec mv {} ./annejulie.blue-world.pl.git \;
```

Comment: what does `>` mean? i tapped your command, and i got that bracket. What should i do now?

Comment: actually it is a result of your command. there is a cursor and it expects to type sth, but i do not know what. i typed `find . -and -not -path './annejulie.blue-world.pl.git*' mv {} ./annejulie.blue-world.pl.git \``

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk looks like you have a backtick at the end of the command - that would make the command not closed for bash, opening a prompt to enter additional stuff inside - try to remove it from the end, it should not return the `>` prompt then